# How can I set the default playback speed in mpv?

Tags: mpv

I want my [mpv player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpv_(media_player)) to start with a default speed of 1.33. Is there a way to achieve it?

How can I configure **mpv** to always start with a default playback speed of, say 1.5, 1.33, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `mpv.conf` just add the line `speed=1.33` or if you're running mpv through command line, use `--speed=1.33`